# Laravel update database record running script

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to update any records in my database running SQL script using artisan. For example, I need to execute such command:

```
UPDATE translations SET field = 'meta_desc' WHERE field = 'page_desc'
```

What the Laravel's sctructure will be the best solution? Seed, migrations, factories?

Comment: Use Console Command. See docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands

Comment: I need to run this script deploying my DB's changes to the DB on production server, so, do you propose me write the new artisan command every time I want to change anything on production? Sorry, but it's a bad solution for me...

Comment: So, you want to make  a command whose content is dynamic and executes different sql queries  Am I right ?

Comment: @Troyer like what?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes, I want to give a possibility to my devops to deploy my DB's changes in production in the easiest way) So, I thins, running script or command in console will be perfect.

Comment: Nice question, I have not too much idea about this, somebody can answer here best of luck.

Comment: I would suggest using migrations here as they will be run only once and in order. Also, if you need to roll back for whatever reason that you'll be able to do so using the `down()` method.

Comment: @RossWilson but migrations are used for structure's changes, isn't it? If you know how to change db's data using migrations, tell me please.

Comment: Yes, primarily you would use the migrations to change the db structure but if  you're making changes that you need to because of changes you've made to your code then I don't see why it would be an issue. Basically, when a migration is run it simply calls the `up()` method (or `down()` if rolling back) so you would only need to have the query in the `up()` method (i.e. remove the `Schema::` code that might have been generated) e.g. `public function run() { DB::select('YOUR QUERY'); }`. You can of course use a fluent query or even `Eloquent` if you want.

Comment: @RossWilson thanks for reply, but I still don't think it is good to make such changes using migrations...

Comment: @PaulBasenko That's fine :). Why do you feel this wouldn't be a good idea? If you don't update the database would it cause a break in your app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to everybody for replies. Ecpesially thanks to @RossWilson for his idea of using migrations for changing DB's data.

But I think, it's not a good solution, because the Laravel's concept involves using migrations for DB structure's changing.

After reading Laravel's manuals I've found that there is a special code structure for working with db's data. It's a [Seed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding). So, I solved my issue using the next seed for my example query above:

1. Created the new seed using artisan command:

   ```
   php artisan make:seed UpdateTranslationsSeeder
   ```
2. Write a code inside the run() method:

   ```
   DB::table('translations')->where('field', 'page_desc')->update(['field' => 'meta_desc']);
   ```
3. Run my seeder in artisan:

   ```
   php artisan db:seed --class=UpdateTranslationsSeeder
   ```

Note: if after running the last command in console I've got an error about class UpdateTranslationsSeeder is undefined run the next command in console to tell Laravel about new classes:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Answer (score 3):

I have adapted Paul Basenko approach to updating existing data for educational purposes. **It was very useful!** Here is my example:

1. Generate a seeder:

   ```
   php artisan make:seed UpdateCustomerSeeder
   ```
2. Add code inside run method:

   ```
   $customers = Customer::all();

   $customers->each(function ($customer_update, $key) {
       $faker = Factory::create('it_IT');

       $customer_update->name = $faker->company;
       $customer_update->website = $faker->domainName;
       $customer_update->tax_number = $faker->vatId();
       $customer_update->phone = $faker->phoneNumber;
       $customer_update->email = $faker->safeEmail;
       $customer_update->street = $faker->streetAddress;
       $customer_update->city = $faker->city;
       $customer_update->zip_code = $faker->postcode;
       $customer_update->notes = $faker->sentence();

       $customer_update->save();
   });
   ```
3. Run seeder:

   ```
   php artisan db:seed --class=UpdateCustomerSeeder
   ```